# Mysql server setup configuration

Tags: mysql, centos, innodb

We have a new centos 6.2 setup. Below is the configuration file. The machine is going to be fully innodb and it has 8Gb ram. What else must I include in the .cnf? I know one major thing is the innodb_buffer_pool if I set 6Gb is it ok?

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

It's getting a little old but this is still one of the best run-downs for a new server configuration:

[What to tune in MySQL Server after installation](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/)

The new [Percona MySQL Configuration Wizard](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/01/26/mysql-configuration-wizard-updated/) is also worth checking out.

Comment: I been to bought the but I am want to know more about this innodb_log_file_size if I adjust now my conf will it have any effect on my log file? There is normally 2 files rite?

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/